# How to use VSCode to remotely edit website files?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, editing

I need to be able to remotely log into web servers for my clients and edit code remotely. I mostly use this for CSS changes, but also am starting to play with PHP as well.

I have tried to get Remote-Editor to work but it won't pick up the .remote file that I placed in the /home folder. The instructions don't really give great details on setting this up.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried these:
https://codepen.io/ginfuru/post/remote-editing-files-with-ssh & 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode

Comment: what OS you use?

Comment: In-case anyone is looking for this solution for Mac: https://superuser.com/questions/1603556/make-vscode-default-editor-for-files-in-filezilla

Answer (score 19):

Use FileZilla, then set VScode as default editor (edit->settings->file editing->filetype associations and insert "php /usr/bin/code"). okey, now u need select your file on FTP and press "View/Edit", then ur file open in VScode editor. Done:)

Comment: In order to know which path to use, and assuming you are on a Linux machine, just type `which code` in the command line and the vscode program path will be displayed. My output was "/snap/bin/code".  And so in the filetype associations, I added:"php /snap/bin/code".

Answer (score 9):

Open Filezilla -> Edit -> Settings -> File Editing -> Filetype associations

Now you will have "Custom filetype associations:" situated on the right pane of the window.
Over there you have to write the command for opening VSCode for PHP files.

**Step 1**: Search and locate the VSCode Exe file setup install directory on your computer. In my case it was (C:\Users\Shubham\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe)

**Step 2**: Copy the directory path link of the ".exe" file and come back to the "Custom filetype associations:" inside Filezilla.

**Step 3**: Now type "php" then give space & paste the directory path that you have copied inside double quotes and then again give space and write "-open". The final code should look something like this

`php "C:\Users\Shubham\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe" -open`

**Step 4**: Click the Okay Button and have a coffee.

Comment: Hi Bro.. Shubham This Side... Worked like a charm :)

Comment: For Mac user: Do Step 1 find your code editor (such as Atom) in your.  Add to the setting the path like ```php /Applications/Atom.app %f```

Answer (score 8):

Use an FTP client (like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)), then set VSCode as the default editor. Anytime you open a file, it will open it in VSCode. I highly recommend that you download all of the code to your own computer and use it as a dev environment, and then, when you're finished with your changes, backup your site, then upload the modified files together. It's not required to edit files on your own machine, but it is recommended if you ever need to revert to an old version for whatever reason (like you made a mistake in the code, and now nothing works right).

Alternatively, you can use an extension like [FTP Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukasz-wronski.ftp-sync) to code locally, and have the files be automatically synced for you.

Comment: In theory, nothing wrong with this approach. I did find, for whatever reason, FileZilla doesn't recognize changes to the editor and still used the OS default. Maybe I didn't have the necessary options in the command line?

Comment: Sometimes we have to take care of the permissions i.e even if we make changes and press save, Filezilla might show the files being transferred successfully but the changes are not seen on the server due to permissions.

Answer (score 7):

Just type this is Filezilla Settings->File Editing-> File Association

php /snap/bin/code

Answer (score 5):

There are several approaches to this that are all editor-agnostic.

First, there is `sshfs`, which is cross-platform and you can install via your OS package manager. A simple approach would be as following:

```
mkdir -p ~/mnt/server
sshfs user@server.example.com:/path/on/server ~/mnt/server
```

Afterwards, you have the complete folder structure from `server.example.com` locally available at `~/mnt/server`. Make sure you set up SSH keys to avoid entering the user password every time. You can find tutorials on that everywhere on the net.

For servers that only offer FTP access (shared hosting and the like), you can use `curlftpfs` in the same fashion.

To close the connection, simply unmount:

```
umount ~/mnt
```

For a GUI-based approach, you have several options. There is [`Transmit`](https://www.panic.com/transmit/) (macOS), which features mounting connections as volumes, [`Forklift`](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/) (macOS) which is a Finder replacement that can do the same, [`ExpanDrive`](https://www.expandrive.com) (macOS/Windows) and my favorite [`Mountain Duck`](https://mountainduck.io) (macOS/Windows).

If you plan to move lots of data, especially a lot of small files, Mountain Duck performs the best in my experience.

Comment: I like the approach of using `sshfs` although it might be scary for some using macOS since you have to allow the kExt.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found it to be unstable, and so now I'll have to look for other approaches. :-)

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me. EC2 instance and opening src Folder in Sublime editor: mkdir -p ~/mnt/server ; 
sshfs user@server.example.com:/path/on/server ~/mnt/server

Answer (score 5):

Open Filezilla and go to **Edit** >> **Settings**

[image]

Click on **File Editing**, and set the radio button to use **Custom Editor**

In the text field below you need to enter the full path to Visual Studio Code, this is usually found in the **/usr/bin/** directory, so you need to enter the following **/usr/bin/code**

Next select the radio button **Always use default editor** and click `OK` to finalise the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's important that you **start Filezilla as an administrator**. That was the reason why it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers I see are for Windows. If anyone wants to associate File Types using Linux in Filezilla, the path is a bit different.

```
htm /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch
html /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch
js /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch
php /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch
```

You do not need to use the extra flags, but they are being used in the Menu Shortcut, so I included them.

Answer (score 3):

To set VS Code as default editor for all type of files in mac use below steps:-

- Click on **Edit** menu
- Then click on **setting** option
- Then find out File Editing and click on it (Not on submenu(Filetype associations))
- Click on custom editor and then browse in application or download and select VS Code. And also click on checkbox "Always use default editor" and then click ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

open filezilla->edit->file editing->use custom editor->browse(find the visual code path)

for find visual code path->right click on the visual code and open location and paste that location to the browse menu and find the visual code short cut

after that press ok on filzilla  it will work fine

Comment: only answer that solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Filezilla` -> `Edit` -> `Settings` -> `File Editing` -> `Filetype associations` then type:

```
php "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %f
```

**Note:** substitute `<username>` with your windows username

**Bonus:**  `php` can be replace with any kind of file format. Just write file extension name on lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I used this registry update to set vscode as my default text file editor (copy & paste into `update.reg`, open regedit and import the file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,4c,00,\
  6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,\
  00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,\
  53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,\
  00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,00
```

After that the registry is updated as follows:

[image]

Of course you should not trust hex encoded registry updates you found in the internet. So copy `22,00 ... 00,00`, remove all backslashes, linebreaks and whitespaces and convert through [one of many hex to ascii online converters](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex%20to%20ascii) to verify the import:

[image]

After you made this change you can even edit text files with vscode through the "edit" context menu entry:

[image]